# Checking empty string in Java

Tags: java, string

I don't know what is wrong with the below code.... I am getting input from a textbox and putting the input in a string. If the textbox is empty it will return a empty string. In the below code

```
   String[] str = new String[9]; 
   for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
       if(str[i].equals("")){
          System.out.println("set " + cmds[i] + " " + str[i]);
          WriteThread.sendCommand("set " + cmds[i] + " " + str[i] + "\n", false);
       }
    }
```

In the above code `str[i]` stores the input text of textboxes and I am trying to check if any element of the array is empty. I also tried with `str[i] == ""` and `str[i] == null` but no luck. The statement inside the if block if i am printing the string `str[i]`, it shows nothing that means it is empty.

Am I doing anything the wrong way?

Comment: What's that you are trying to check ? You check if the string is empty and then do a print, and the result as you say is something like "set" +... since you can't see an empty string :). Probably you want to test the not condition: i.e if(!str[i].equals("")) ..

Comment: Really, simple check if() condition ...

Comment: Do you think you could edit your question to make it more understandable? From the comments and answers, I can see I'm not the only one that is not sure what you really want... :-(

Comment: Sorry for typo mistake. Actually that was as you hav mentioned the not condition.

Comment: not resolving the problem, but it usually preferred to write 
 if("".equals(str[i])) to avoid NullPointerExceptions

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could try :

```
if (str[i] == null || str[i].trim().equals("")){
// your code
}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use the [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) to check a String:

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(str[i]) {
    ...
}
```

`StringUtils.isBlank` is checking if the String is `null` or empty (i.e. if it is equals to `""` when all blank characters are removed).

Comment: what happens if someone just enters space?

Comment: @AshishDonvir `StringUtils.isBlank(" ")` returns `true`. If you want this test to return `false`, you can use `StringUtils.isEmpty(...)` instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend

```
if (str[i] == null || str[i].trim().length==0){
// your code
}
```

or Java 6 onward

```
if (str[i] == null || str[i].trim().isEmpty()){
// your code
}
```

Instead of using equals() because equals() method is overkill to test for an empty String

Answer (score 0):

The above code only executes if the string is empty, is that the desired behavior? Also declaring str as new right before the loop pretty much guarantees it will be empty.

If you are trying to assign the values from textboxes you will need to have those assignments somewhere before the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I actually tried to run your code snippet and got a NullPointerException on your conditional

> str[i].equals("")

str[i] == null worked for me. Are you sure you put the right code in your question. It seems odd to be testing for an empty string of an empty array you just initialized.

Answer (score 0):

A very simple solution can be like this.

```
if(str[] != null && !str[].equals(""))
```